# De-zephyr The Solution!

Tags: no-computers, chess, optimization

Here's another original chess problem of mine for you all to solve today!

In the following position, White wants to stalemate Black even though they can win, for unknown, unclear, unexplained, and illogical reasons.

[image]

In how many moves can White forcibly stalemate Black? You may only use your 100%, organic, al naturale brain power!

Comment: At times like these, there's nothing so devastating as being told you're on the right track. I'll remove my string of moves now.

Comment: I was desperately hoping I was on the _wrong_ track, because I was hitting a big trouble spot in my given line. :/ So yes, a joke.

Comment: That knight on f8 is making a fool out of me after Rxa7+ :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The title means

> that we are going to use the windmill technique (Zephyr is the name of a wind).

Here is a solution: [apronus link](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?p=Ar_____n__B____p___b___p_______pn______pK____NQR_pbppp_r______Nqk0w&m=Rh6*_Qh7_Rxh7*_Kg8_Rxg7*_Kh8_Rxe7*_Kg8_Rg7*_Kh8_Rxd7*_Kg8_Rg7*_Kh8_Rxc7*_Kg8_Rg7*_Kh8_Rxb7*_Kg8_Rg7*_Kh8_Rxa7*_Kg8_Rg7*_Kh8_Ng6*_Nxg6_Rxg6*_Kh7_Rg7*_Kh8_Rxg5*_Kh7_Rg7*_Kh8_Rxg4*_Kh7_Rg7*_Kh8_Rxg3*_Kh7_Rg7*_Kh8_Rxg2*_Kh7_Rg7*_Kh8_Rxg1*_Kh7_Qg7*_Bxg7_Rxg7*_Kh8_Bxa1).

PGN:

> [FEN "5Nqk/pbppp1r1/4NQR1/6pK/6pn/2b3p1/1B4p1/r5n1 w - -"]
>  1. Rh6+ Qh7 2. Rxh7+ Kg8 3. Rxg7+ Kh8 4. Rxe7+ Kg8
>  5. Rg7+ Kh8 6. Rxd7+ Kg8 7. Rg7+ Kh8 8. Rxc7+ Kg8
>  9. Rg7+ Kh8 10. Rxb7+ Kg8 11. Rg7+ Kh8 12. Rxa7+ Kg8
>  13. Rg7+ Kh8 14. Ng6+ Nxg6 15. Rxg6+ Kh7 16. Rg7+ Kh8
>  17. Rxg5+ Kh7 18. Rg7+ Kh8 19. Rxg4+ Kh7 20. Rg7+ Kh8
>  21. Rxg3+ Kh7 22. Rg7+ Kh8 23. Rxg2+ Kh7 24. Rg7+ Kh8
>  25. Rxg1+ Kh7 26. Qg7+ Bxg7 27. Rxg7+ Kh8 28. Bxa1

Note that

> the bishop could capture any time during the second phase, but this would result in an even faster stalemate. [See this](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?p=Ar_____n__B____p___b___p_______pn______pK____NQR_pbppp_r______Nqk0w&m=Rh6*_Qh7_Rxh7*_Kg8_Rxg7*_Kh8_Rxe7*_Kg8_Rg7*_Kh8_Rxd7*_Kg8_Rg7*_Kh8_Rxc7*_Kg8_Rg7*_Kh8_Rxb7*_Kg8_Rg7*_Kh8_Rxa7*_Kg8_Rg7*_Kh8_Ng6*_Nxg6_Rxg6*_Kh7_Rg7*_Kh8_Rxg5*_Kh7_Rg7*_Kh8_Rxg4*_Kh7_Rg7*_Kh8_Rxg3*_Bxf6_Bxf6*_Kh7_Rg7*_Kh8_Rxg2*_Kh7_Rg7*_Kh8_Rxg1*_Kh7_Bxa1) for instance.  If we assume that the opponent tries to make it as long as they can, then the above is the solution, in 27 moves and a half.

Comment: Very nice solution - I went to bed with this puzzle on my mind and thought of the solution as I was going to bed, but the computer was already off. Congrats!

Comment: @RewanDemontay yep! A beautiful solution (and puzzle)!

Comment: @RewanDemontay Zephyr is a wind, and the technique used here is called a windmill in chess.

Comment: Plus it starts with the letter "z," and "zwickmule" is another word meaning windmill.

Comment: I'm perfectly fine with that! Have seen my selfmate windmill puzzle yet?

Comment: @RewanDemontay Do you mean a second one? (I've solved one)

Comment: Yeah. Search for "The Slaughterhouse" in the bar and you'll find it

Comment: @RewanDemontay Thanks! So I'll cite you as my source of inspiration then.

Comment: You're very welcome! Would you mind a tip on where to find other windmill puzzles for inspiration?

Comment: @RewanDemontay Nice one, I hadn't seen it! No thanks, I prefer not to eat too much at a time, it takes away the pleasure :)