# Don't bully your cousin at Reversi

Tags: optimization, board-games, reversi

Title (only) inspired by [Don't bully your little sister at chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86904/dont-bully-your-little-sister-at-chess)

### Prologue

Well, this happened when I played Reversi with my cousin a few days ago...

[image]

I, not being as nice as @Arnold `:P`, I decided to continue to bully my cousin, but to cut her pain.

### Rules

- Each move, no matter white or black, must capture pieces
- This is a circumstance where your enemy is not a perfect logician, (like my cousin `XD`), so you may assume that your opponent is helping you.
- You can choose beinhg white or black.

### The Puzzle

Create a circumstance of `X-0` or `0-X` with **minimum** X.

### Tier-breaker

Less steps needed wins

### OP's Words

[reversi](/questions/tagged/reversi) is temporary. Please feel free to retag for me. Thanks!

Comment: Welp, I already know someone solved this before and probably the least we could do...

Comment: Thanks for the reference :) nice problem! It's a pity that the solution can be found online as @athin pointed out.

Comment: Well in fact I'm not completely sure I understand the question, because if it means what I think it means, then there can be no tie-break as indicated: the amount of steps needed is always equal to X-4.

Comment: @Arnaud really? if so, can you prove it while providing the answer? i'll give you the checkmark then :)

Comment: Related: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/39166/whats-the-least-amount-of-pieces-on-an-othello-board-where-black-or-white-cant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remark regarding the tie-breaker rule:

> After each move, the total amount of stones (black or white) increases by $1$ (and so does the amount of moves!). Since there are four stones on the board before any move is played, it follows that a score of $X:0$ can only be reached after $X-4$ moves. Therefore there will never be a tie-break in the way that is indicated in the rules.

Solution:

> $13:0$ after $9$ moves [image]